# Reuse SimpleWebServiceOutboundGateway in multiple IntegrationFlows in Spring Integration

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl, spring-integration-ws

Given I have 2 `IntegrationFlow`s which reference the same `SimpleWebServiceOutboundGateway` bean:

```java
@Bean
IntegrationFlow getDataA(
        Jaxb2Marshaller xmlMarshaller,
        SimpleWebServiceOutboundGateway webServiceOutboundGateway) {
    return IntegrationFlows.from("getDataA")
            .transform(marshaller(xmlMarshaller))
            .transform(new ResultToStringTransformer())
            .handle(webServiceOutboundGateway)
            .transform(unmarshaller(xmlMarshaller))
            .get();
}

@Bean
IntegrationFlow getDataB(
        Jaxb2Marshaller xmlMarshaller,
        SimpleWebServiceOutboundGateway webServiceOutboundGateway) {
    return IntegrationFlows.from("getDataB")
            .transform(marshaller(xmlMarshaller))
            .transform(new ResultToStringTransformer())
            .handle(webServiceOutboundGateway)
            .transform(unmarshaller(xmlMarshaller))
            .get();
}

@Bean
SimpleWebServiceOutboundGateway webServiceOutboundGateway(HttpComponentsMessageSender httpComponentsMessageSender) {
    SimpleWebServiceOutboundGateway outboundGateway = new SimpleWebServiceOutboundGateway("url");
    outboundGateway.setMessageSender(httpComponentsMessageSender);
    return outboundGateway;
}
```

When I execute the code I am getting:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An AbstractMessageProducingHandler may only be referenced once (webServiceOutboundGateway) - use @Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE) on @Bean definition.
```

When I add `@Scope(SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)` to `webServiceOutboundGateway`, I'm getting the same exception

How can I reuse `webServiceOutboundGateway` in both flows?

Comment: Prototype scope scope should be all you need; however, this looks odd `from("getDataA")`. `.from(String)` means from channel name, but you have from this `IntegrationFlow`.

Answer (score 0):

I just copied your code into a new app, fixed the channel names and putting the gatway in prototype scope worked for me...

```java
@Bean
@Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
SimpleWebServiceOutboundGateway webServiceOutboundGateway() {
    SimpleWebServiceOutboundGateway outboundGateway = new SimpleWebServiceOutboundGateway("url");
    return outboundGateway;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, it fails to start for me. I use `org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-ws -> 4.3.14.RELEASE` and `org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-core:4.3.14.RELEASE`. Could it be the reason?

Comment: Yes, that's the problem; I am not sure why, but `@Scope(scopeName = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)` solves it. That said, why such an old version? 4.3.x won't be supported for much longer; if you are using Boot 1.5; it went end of life long ago.